# Compiling android system apps with make

Tags: android, build, makefile, apk, dex

I am trying to compile android system package apps using

> make

but the compiled APK is missing classes.dex file.

I have setup [initialized](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) and [downloaded](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) the android build environment properly. 
I am using *aosp_arm-user* as *lunch* build target.

I am compiling the system apps using command

> make -j16 Mms

The apk gets generated in

> /out/target/product/generic/system/priv-app/Mms.apk

on installing the generated apk using

> adb install Mms.apk

the install fails with the following error

> Failure [INSTALL FAILED DEXPOT]

Logcat shows the following error

> DexOptZ: zip archive '/data/app/com.android.mms-1.apk' does not include classes.dex

Any hints to solve the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you get an error, it is usually good to re-build without the `-j N` switch. This way you see the last error message.

Comment: Tried without the j switch, didn't help.

Comment: Without j is better only in that when an error happens, you see the last error message in the end (rather than in the middle of a few K of text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User builds are pre-dexopt'd, meaning that dexopt runs on the apk as part of the build process, and produces a .odex file beside the .apk, rather than a classes.dex inside the apk.

Use an eng or userdebug build to prevent that from happening automatically. e.g.

```
lunch aosp_arm-userdebug
```

There may be an environment variable you could use to control the behavior as well.